# c# service "The netwerk bios command limit has been reached" error why and whats the best solution?

Tags: c#, service, .net-3.5, filesystemwatcher

I have a service that opens multiple watchers to watch multiple folders. After watching folders for a certain amount of time I get the "The network bios command limit has been reached".

As I read on [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810886) this is caused by having more long term requests than allowed.

I believe this occurs due to the below error handling code i have, which is triggered by the watchers error event. This starts a new instance of the watcher by calling the WatchFile method again. I believe this leaves the old now defunct watcher running and starts a new watcher but i am afraid stopping the watcher will either prevent it from starting it up again or will stop all instances based on the watcher.

Or am I wrong and is the error dependent on the amount of changes? This would cause 100 files to drop in at the same time to cause this error.

I was thinking of stopping and starting the service whenever I run in this error but this would not solve the problem itself but just hide it. Is there a better solution to it?

```
private static void watcherError(String directory, Boolean intray, ErrorEventArgs e, FileSystemWatcher watcher)
{
    Exception watchException = e.GetException();
    EventLog.WriteEntry("WhiteFileMover", String.Concat("error gedetecteerd, watcher werd herstart  -  ", watchException.Message), EventLogEntryType.Information);
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    while (!watcher.EnableRaisingEvents)
    {
        try
        {
            // This will throw an error at the
            // watcher.NotifyFilter line if it can't get the path.
            WatchFile(directory, intray);
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            // Sleep for a bit; otherwise, it takes a bit of
            // processor time
            EventLog.WriteEntry("WhiteFileMover", String.Concat("Failed to restart watcher, retrying in 5 seconds  -  ", exp.Message), EventLogEntryType.Warning);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about disposing the old watcher that ran into the error?

Comment: @Kolja if i do watcher.dispose, will that only dispose that instance or all instances based on watcher? for ex i have created 3 instances of watcher but only want to dispose one of them.

Comment: It will dispose the current instance the variable is pointing to, which is the one that failed. After that you can create a new instance. But You don't dispose it and just create a new one what will likely end up with a bunch of wasted watcher instances.

Comment: Andy, I have exactly same problem. Can you please share your solution? I am thinking about using one of 2 solutions here. Either use directory polling or write a FSW pool to return one object for same root directories. but, i am sure both will have issues of their own. Also, making pool for FSW instead of creating multiple FSW will only delay the issue but eventually i'll run into Network BIOS error and i've to restart watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
```

You passed in a FileSystemWatcher variable, but completely ignored the passed value. Instead, you created a new instance.  Not only that, but you fail to correctly dispose the instance. My guess is that you have a bunch of old FileSystemWatcher objects hanging around waiting to be collected. Each of those will hold on to some real file system resources from the operating system. Over time, you run out of available file handles.

Comment: I have added a watcher.dispose before creating the new watcher, but the error stays the same. is there more i need to do before the old watcher is removed from memory?

Comment: @Andy Dispose() has **nothing** to do with memory. Thankfully, memory isn't your problem (file handles are).  But the real problem is that you shouldn't create a new watcher all the time. You want to use **exactly one** watcher for your app, and pass around references to that one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the filewatcher and define the event handlers?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx