# FileSystemWatcher Exception - The network BIOS command limit has been reached

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-server-2008, filesystemwatcher

I have a C# (.Net framework 3.5) based windows service application on Windows 2008 Server which is monitoring 22 folders on a remote server/network path. Every now and then I will get an exception in the log

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network BIOS command limit has been reached.

I have tried increasing the [InternalBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to MAX (64K) but it doesn't have any effect on the exception.

I have defined it like:

At Class level:

```
FileSystemWatcher fsw;
```

In Initialization method

```
fsw = new FileSystemWatcher("FolderUNC");
fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
//m_fsw.InternalBufferSize = 65536; -- Commented out to default 8K
fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size;
fsw.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
fsw.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnFileSystemWatcherError);
fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

I am also making sure that I dispose the `FileSystemWatcher` object on Error or on stopping the service. Like

```
if (fsw != null)
    fsw.Dispose();
```

I have tried following the [article KB-810886](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810886), but since my server is Windows Server 2008 I don't have registry keys for `MaxCmds`, `MaxMpxCT` etc. I have already looked at related questions on Stackoverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065034/c-sharp-service-the-netwerk-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached-error-why-and) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050656/the-network-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached), but none of them seems to have resolved the issue.

Any help or guidance in resolving the issue is appreciated.

EDIT: I have also added a similar [question on ServerFaults](https://serverfault.com/questions/597889/filesystemwatcher-exception-the-network-bios-command-limit-has-been-reached) , about how to raise the limit of `MaxCMDs` on Windows 2008 server.

EDIT 2: I have create keys for MaxCmds and MaxMpxCt on my server hosting windows service and set their values to `250`, but it didn't have any effect. I followed this article. http://alitarhini.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/299/

Comment: A FileSystemWatcher is an *expensive* operating system resource.  The file system has to do a lot of work to generate these notifications.  Your well South of what your operating system considers reasonable.  You of course don't fix that by adjusting the unreasonability limit, you fix it by using less watchers.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for the comment. I have to monitor 22 folders, and that might increase in future, I am thinking about ditching `FileSystemWatcher` all together and using a timer to monitor all the directories periodically in multiple threads. Do you think that this approach would be less resource hungry ?

Comment: You'll generate a lot more unnecessary network traffic, another resource.  As long as you set the timer's interval to a reasonable value, like 10 minutes, then that's no real problem.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks again, That will be a *no-go* for me. Could you please tell me how can I increase the limit ? and do I have to increase the limit on my server hosting windows service ? or on the file server which has the folder to monitor. Thanks again.

Comment: It is not on topic here, ask at serverfault.com

Comment: @HansPassant -- you or me are unable to apply a judgement to how often he should poll or how many he should poll.  Each situation is different, and simply discounting his question with "it's too resource intenstive" isn't helpful or useful.    Also - monitoring 22 folders is NOT resource intensive in the least.



user2711965 -- are you able to use maybe .NET 4.5 with its caching to use hostfilewatcher?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.hostfilechangemonitor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user2711965 -- if you can't get around it, have your service do a timed polling of all the files and folders you need to monitor.   Once every X seconds or minutes -- walk through your list of directories and check them.

There are plenty of networking 3rd party apps that do do that, though - to make sure mounts are still mounted, folders are accessible, all that stuff - might want to look into that before you roll your own.

Regardless, "pinging" 20-30 folders every minute or two is not resource intensive or complicated.

Comment: You are trying to shoot the messenger, I did not set that limit.  Kinda pointless to expect anybody to be helpful in a comment btw.  It still isn't on topic here, "ask at serverfault" is only as far as I should take it.  Current answers strongly suggest that this is the right way.

Comment: @user2711965, what did you end up using? I've same issue and i don't want to use Polling solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to consider in the decision of "should you ditch the FSW and roll your own (RYO)?":

- You currently monitor 22 folders. Will this number go up? How high?
- How many files are in each folder? A few? or a few thousand?
- What is the nature of the solution? Is this a drop-folder solution, where you immediately move a file somewhere else? Or a backup-type solution, where you're diffing files in place? Each of these will have an impact on how you're interacting with the remote file.
- Are you performing remote file operations that might be generating additional FSW events? FSW events are raised for many things, from renaming, editing, changing attributes, flags and permissions.
- How many monitored file operations do you need to be able to process per second? A few? Or a few thousand?
- FSW uses optimized calls in the network stack that will raise events from the monitored OS (assuming the target OS is >Windows 98), as opposed to a roll-your-own where you would have to pull the entire list of files down, and then diff it for changes. FSW wins where there are lots of files; RYO *might* win if there are only a few. If your monitored file systems aren't Windows machines, FSW simply polls files in the same way that a RYO solution would.
- FSW can get overloaded by high throughput. Realize that a single operation can raise many events to the FSW. Be sure you've set your filters of file type and event type to filter out the noise.
- FSW uses non-paged memory. It can be expensive, even cripple throughput on a busy server without enough RAM. 22 FSW instances can get hairy with a quickness.
- Keep the FSW buffer as empty as you can! **Consider segregating the thread(s) with the FSWs from the thread(s) that handle the event, so the events that the FSW raises are handled and cleared from the buffer immediately.** If the number of concurrently active files is in the dozens, you can simply kick off a new task in the *Changed event; if the number of concurrently active files is in the thousands, you'll want to implement a producer/consumer pattern to do the work.

Comment: +1 for your answer, I know there  is no straight forward answer to my particular problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have those keys, on your Windows Registry, you can create it as DWORD with a value between 0 and 65535.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters

Comment: Where should I create those keys ? on File Server or on the Server hosting the Windows service ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example file system poller.  I'd be interested in how it performs in your scenario.

```
void Main()
{
    var watcher = new DirectoryWatcher("C:\\test\\", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
    watcher.Notification += (sender, args) => 
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} was {1}", args.FileName, args.NotificationType));

    watcher.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop.");
    Console.ReadLine();

    watcher.Stop();
}

public class DirectoryWatcher
{
    public DirectoryWatcher(string directory, TimeSpan pollingFrequency)
    {
        this.Directory = directory;
        this.PollingFrequency = pollingFrequency;
    }

    public string Directory { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan PollingFrequency { get; set; }

    public System.Threading.Timer Timer { get; set; }

    private long ProcessCount;

    public void Start()
    {
        this.Timer = new Timer(Tick, null, 0, (int)PollingFrequency.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Timer.Dispose();
    }

    DirectoryState previousState;

    private void Tick(object stateInfo)
    {
        if(Interlocked.Increment(ref ProcessCount) == 1)
        {
            try
            {
                if(previousState == null)
                {
                    // First Run.
                    // Tell listeners about files that already exist in the directory.
                    previousState = new DirectoryState(this.Directory);

                    foreach(var file in previousState.Files)
                    {
                        RaiseNotification(file.Key, DirectoryWatcherNotifiction.StartUp);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var currentState = new DirectoryState(this.Directory);
                    NotifyChanges(previousState, currentState);
                    previousState = currentState;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                if(this.Error != null)
                {
                    this.Error(this, new ErrorEventArgs(ex));
                }
            }
        }
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref ProcessCount);
    }

    private void NotifyChanges(DirectoryState previous, DirectoryState current)
    {
        // Notify changes and deletions.
        foreach(string fileName in previous.Files.Keys)
        {
            if(current.Files.ContainsKey(fileName))
            {
                if(!current.Files[fileName].Equals(previous.Files[fileName]))
                {
                    RaiseNotification(fileName, DirectoryWatcherNotifiction.Changed);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RaiseNotification(fileName, DirectoryWatcherNotifiction.Deleted);
            }
        }

        // Notify new files.
        foreach(string fileName in current.Files.Keys)
        {
            if(!previous.Files.ContainsKey(fileName))
            {
                RaiseNotification(fileName, DirectoryWatcherNotifiction.Created);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RaiseNotification(string fileName, DirectoryWatcherNotifiction notificationType)
    {
        if(this.Notification != null)
        {
            this.Notification(this, new DirectoryWatcherEventArgs(fileName, notificationType));
        }
    }

    public EventHandler<DirectoryWatcherEventArgs> Notification { get; set; }
    public EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs> Error { get; set; }
}

public class DirectoryWatcherEventArgs
{
    public DirectoryWatcherEventArgs(string fileName, DirectoryWatcherNotifiction notificationType)
    {
        this.FileName = fileName;
        this.NotificationType = notificationType;
    }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DirectoryWatcherNotifiction NotificationType { get; set; }
}

public enum DirectoryWatcherNotifiction
{
    StartUp,
    Deleted,
    Changed,
    Created
}

public class DirectoryState
{
    private DirectoryState()
    {
        this.Files = new Dictionary<string, DirectoryFileInfo>();
    }

    public DirectoryState(string directory) 
        : this()
    {
        this.DirectoryName = directory;

        foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory))
        {
            this.Files.Add(file, new DirectoryFileInfo(file));
        }
    }

    public string DirectoryName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, DirectoryFileInfo> Files { get; set; }
}

public class DirectoryFileInfo
{
    public DirectoryFileInfo(string fileName)
    {   
        var info = new FileInfo(fileName);
        this.LastWriteTime = info.LastWriteTime;
        this.FileSize = info.Length;
    }

    public DateTime LastWriteTime { get; set; }
    public long FileSize { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(DirectoryFileInfo other)
    {
        return this.LastWriteTime == other.LastWriteTime && this.FileSize == other.FileSize;
    }
}
```